# vshost.exe impact on prevhost.exe

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, clr

Issue : 
For viewing the preview of my own format files in windows explorer , custom preview handler library is built using 4.0 framework and registered using regasm.exe. Everything works well.

The problem is with app.vshost.exe[when a console app or windows app is opened in visual studio framework 4.0 and later],previewhost.exe is not firing.if visual studio is closed or framework change to 3.5 or lesser, prevhost.exe is working.

Itried to disable the Hosting Process,and it's working well.

Is there any workaround to overcome this  issue, because I can't force the client to disable the Hosting Process.